# Team foundation server on the Mac with Vim

Tags: eclipse, macos, vim, tfs

I'm using Vim on a Mac for front-end development and was recently hired at the company that uses Team Foundation Server as their version control system.

I would hate to have to switch to using Visual Studio on Windows because I'm so used to Vim and the Mac.

I found [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4240) and was hoping that would be a possible solution. I would still like to avoid editing code in Eclipse. However I wouldn't mind opening Eclipse to do version control stuff.

I'm very unfamiliar with Eclipse and Team Foundation Server (not VCS in general) and I need some advice on how to actually use it.
I'm able to connect to the server and find the project I have to work on, but from here I'm lost. [This](http://cl.ly/image/3u0M1Q2N0L1x) is the window I'm stuck at.

Anyone who are in a similar situation and could offer some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done the hard bit I think, firstly you should be able to safely ignore the Work Item and Build "folders" unless someone explicity tells you to use work items, at which point they can show you what you need to know as it works exactly the same as in Visual Studio.

If you double click on the Source Control folder it will open a new window which will show you the source "tree". To be able to Get, Checkout and add source files to the tree you'll need to [set up a workspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg490753%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Once you've done this then you can get the code and check out.

With Team Explorer Everywhere You also have the option of using the [tf command line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873092.aspx) in the Mac terminal. This would eliminate the need for eclipse. (I'm assuming that as a Vim user you're not afraid to use the terminal)

Another option might be [svnBridge](http://svnbridge.codeplex.com/) however I think you need the server version if you're using a Mac, and this requires a site to be installed in the TFS application server which might not be an option.

Finally [TFS now offers support for integration with GIT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2012/08/13/announcing-git-integration-with-tfs.aspx).